# Since all classes extend Object, and Object is a class, how can Object extend Object?

Tags: java, object, inheritance

This isn't really too much of a programming question, but I've been doing a lot of Java lately, and wondering about the language. The question is quite self-explanatory. Classes all extend `Object`, and `Object` must be an object, since classes `extend` it. And since objects are classes, how does `Object` extend `Object`, if `Object` is a class itself? If I make an object that extends itself, I get: `Cycle detected: the type MovingObject cannot extend/implement itself or one of its own member types`.

So, how can this be explained?

EDIT: I wouldn't call this a duplicate, as the question that this was marked as a duplicate was asking for a list of classes which do not extend Object. I was asking how can Object, if all classes extend it, extend itself.

Comment: I've added another duplicate that does explicitly address your question (even though the original duplicate answers your question indirectly).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`java.lang.Object` is special in this way. The Java language specification, section [8.1.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.4) states:

> The extends clause must not appear in the definition of the class Object, or a compile-time error occurs, because it is the primordial class and has no direct superclass.

If you look at any implementation of the Java standard library, you'll find that the source of `java.lang.Object` does in fact not have an extends clause (and because the Object class is primordial and has special treatment in the spec, there's no `extends Object` implicitly present).

Additionally, you may observe that the value of `Object.class.getSuperclass()` is precisely the null reference.

Digging into native code, it appears that this rule is enforced [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/b4ee249eb1c4/src/share/vm/ci/ciInstanceKlass.cpp#l323), after a few layers of delegation.